# Find distance between widgets in layout

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have some labels in a frame set to a grid layout. I would like to find out the x coordinate for them so I can find the distance between them as this will change depending on screen size. but when I try

```
print(self.ui.label_1.x())
print(self.ui.label_2.x())
```

I get 0 for both.

I understand this is because they are in a grid and don't technically have coordinates. but is there another way to find the distance between them?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)? If not, you should. Otherwise, are you trying to manually set the geometry of widgets? If so, why? Geometries should not be overridden when layouts are used, trying to do so is almost always caused by a bad usage of layouts. In any case, widgets are always placed at `0, 0` during initialization, they are layed out only when the layout is activated and the parent is resized (which happens at least once *after* it is shown).

Comment: Try: `QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: print((self.ui.label_1.x(), self.ui.label_2.x()))`.